Recuperar datos de mi BD con parametros de fechas
Tengo problemas al momento de recuperar datos de mi BD, revisé la consulta en mi phpMyAdmin y me arroja datos correctos con las fechas ingresadas, por ejemplo: '2020-05-02' como fecha inicial y '2020-06-02' como fecha final. Mi campo fecha_historial está definido de tipo timestamp.
Al momento de realizar las pruebas desde el frontend, me devuelve los campos solicitados en la consulta, pero solo con fechas '0000-00-00 00:00:00' y no dentro los parámetros de fechas que se solicita.
Código de la API:
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

require("conexion.php"); // importa el archivo de la conexion a la BD
$conexion = conexion();

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT p.nombre_paciente, p.edad_paciente, h.fecha_historial, h.dx_historial, h.o_historial 
                                        FROM paciente p INNER JOIN historial h ON p.id_paciente=h.id_paciente 
                                        WHERE h.fecha_historial >= ".$_GET['fechaIni']." AND h.fecha_historial <= ".$_GET['fechaEnd'].";");

// Recorre el resultado y lo guarda en un array
while( $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
    $datos[]= $resultado;
}

$json = json_encode($datos); // Genera el json con los datos obtenidos

//Envio de informacion del JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;
?>

Código del servicio:
getReportes(fechaIni:any, fechaEnd:any){
    return this.http.get(`${this.URL}ObtenerReportes.php?fechaIni=${fechaIni}&fechaEnd=${fechaEnd}`);
}

Código del componente:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PacienteService } from 'src/app/services/paciente.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reporte',
  templateUrl: './reporte.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reporte.component.css']
})
export class ReporteComponent implements OnInit {

  reportes: any;

  fechaIni: any;
  fechaEnd: any;

  tablaCosto = document.getElementById("tablaReport");

  constructor(private pacienteService: PacienteService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  VerReporte(fechaIni:any, fechaEnd:any){
    this.pacienteService.getReportes(fechaIni,fechaEnd).subscribe((resp:any)=>{
      this.reportes = resp;
      console.log(fechaIni,fechaEnd);
    }
    ,
    ()=>{
      alert('Es necesario ingresar fechas válidas.');
    }
    );
  }
}

Espero haber realizado una buena pregunta y que se comprenda el problema planteado.
Agredezco de antemano el interes prestado por responder este caso en particular.

Hay que mejorar el código en Angular, está algo confuso y tienes malas prácticas como usar mayúscula al iniciar el nombre de la función, se recomienda que sea camelCase, por otro lado, estás usando any para todo ¿no sabes cual es el tipo de dato que estás usando? Para crear interfaces puedes usar Quicktype.io (copia y pegas el JSON), por otro lado el manejo de errores lo puedes hacer en el servicio para evitar repetir el código (D.R.Y)

Tampoco se recomienda manipular el DOM de forma manual, puedes usar ViewChild para eso.

aportando algo sobre las buenas practicas, en cuanto a las consultas sql, lo correcto sería utilizar un procedimientos en vez de utilizar consultas directas en código, ya que en caso de tener que corregir la consulta, se hace solo en la base de datos, y no en el código fuente de la app, lo que llevaría a tener que re-compilar todo el proyecto.

Con lo que pones es difícil saber el problema. Depura la aplicación con las herramientas de desarrollador y revisa qué valores tienen los parámetros que  se están enviando al backend.

@SerNocturno porque seria lo correcto? eso depende el entorno, la db y muchas otras cosas mas...  Con respecto al problema, los datos estan bien?? y en el mismo formato que en la db?

@gbianchi el hacer la consulta sql directamente en el código fuente no es recomendable, ya que los datos deben ser manipulados sobre la base de datos no sobre el código fuente de la aplicación, eso dificulta el mantenimiento, además de que va en contra de los principios de separación de responsabilidades, además que en algunos casos puede se susceptible a inyección de código. Lo recomendable es utilizar procedimientos almacenados o vistas, en casos muy particulares consultas directas, pero aun así los datos siempre deben ser parametrizados

Por eso mismo digo, eso depende de muchos factores que tienen que ver especificamente con la arquitectura de cada lugar. Decir que es recomendable, no es recomendable.. y ninguna consulta que hagas en cualquier lado deberia ser susceptible a inyeccion, si es asi, el problema es otro...

¿Qué llega exactamente en $_GET['fechaIni'] y $_GET['fechaEnd']?

¿Ya intentaste hacer la llamada a tu API con postman?
